# Whats is twoPtrValue in Tcl

Tags: c++, tcl

Many places in c++ code.
`internalRep.twoPtrValue.ptr1` is used to get `Tcl_Obj*`.

What exactly is this and why this is use in C++/Tcl implementation .
I am working in legacy code and not able to understand its uses.
Can any one explain

Answer (score 0):

The Tcl library uses the [`Tcl_Obj`](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/Object.html) type internally to represent values in the interpreter. According to the original language specification "everything is a string" it has to be able to hold a string representation of the value but also caches various internal values depending on the type. The library defines a union in one of the fields (internalRep) and the specific type held is accessed via the union members. For some types it makes sense to hold two pointer values and as this has been supported in the union you get the code you are enquiring about.

More generally though, the internal representation is only for use by the functions defined by the [Tcl_ObjType](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/ObjectType.html) structure that defines this object type in Tcl. You should examine those functions for how they use these pointer values.

Answer (score 0):

The internal representation of a `Tcl_Obj` is a holder for an interpretation of the value according to the definition pointed to by the `typePtr` field. For example, if a value is `1.25` and has been interpreted as a double-precision float, the `typePtr` will point to the constant `tclDoubleType` structure, and the `doubleValue` of the internal representation (which is overall a `union`) will be used.

Some types use the two-pointer internal representation; what those pointers mean will depend on the type. For example, with lists the first pointer is used for pointing to the array of values in the list (plus some metadata) and the second pointer is normally NULL but is other things when doing complex nested updates. But the `ptr1` is *in itself* just a raw pointer. The implementations of the object types determine what casts should be used.

(Tcl's type system is *utterly* different to that of C++. It's also a C library; it does things that are usually considered to be awful practice in C++ due to them not being safe. But they're used safely in Tcl's implementation.)